# Some emoji icons cut in half when rendered in my zsh custom prompt (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, zsh, emoji, oh-my-zsh

I'm using ZSH with oh-my-zsh in Cygwin, and was using the "Cloud" theme, which put the Cloud emoji (☁) in front of the prompt. I liked that but wanted to try customizing it slightly to show a different image. However, some emoji characters (at least those I've tried) apparently will not render properly.

This is the cloud theme as it shipped with ohmyzsh:

```
if [[ -z $ZSH_THEME_CLOUD_PREFIX ]]; then
    ZSH_THEME_CLOUD_PREFIX='☁'
fi

PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}$ZSH_THEME_CLOUD_PREFIX %{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[green]%}%c % {$fg_bold[cyan]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'
```

This is what it looks like with that theme:

[image: ZSH terminal cloud theme screenshot]

I tried swapping out the cloud emoji with another, as such:

```
if [[ -z $ZSH_THEME_PAW_PREFIX ]]; then
    ZSH_THEME_PAW_PREFIX=''
fi

PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[yellow]%}$ZSH_THEME_PAW_PREFIX %{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[green]%}%c %{$fg_bold[cyan]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'
```

However, it only shows half the emoji image in my console:

[image: ZSH terminal paw theme screenshot]

I will note that I'm using [Source Code Pro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecodepro.adobe/) monospace font in both instances. It looks to me like the emoji is being rendered in a narrower space in the second example. Is there a way I can fix this? Or rather, why would there be a difference? Is it something with how these emoji are encoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a `zsh` issue, it's a combination of problems with the terminal emulator and the character in question.

Here's the character used in my prompt:

[image]

I use a [monospace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospace) font: [Inconsolata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconsolata). This means that all the characters line up vertically. However, the emoji character you're asking about is too wide (it takes up two character spaces).

I *think* this means that that character is typeset 1.7-2 times wider than a normal character, and your terminal emulator doesn't know how to handle it. When it's rendered, it displays the normal character width, unfortunately cutting off the right-hand portion of the character.

I would recommend:

- Finding a different terminal emulator or font: I'm not sure whether it's your combination, or specifically the font, or specifically the emulator. (I don't use Cygwin, and can't recommend any Windows-based software).
- Changing characters to one that doesn't overflow the character width.

**Note:** Interestingly, your first example is also too wide:

[image]

(it should be directly under the `a`). Perhaps it's just that the paw-print character is *far* too wide (double) instead of a little (1.5-ish).

You **could try** setting the character with a space after it:

```
ZSH_THEME_PAW_PREFIX=' '
```

but I don't know if this will work.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that I might have to do this. I am using minTTY for my terminal emulator, by the way. I did try padding with spaces and even non-zero width unprintable characters to no avail. I was hoping I could embed some codes in PS1 to change how it renders that character, but I suppose that isn't going to happen. I'll look around. Thanks!